# Solving the Weierstrass differential equation for $g_2^3=27g_3^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve the Weierstrass Differential Equation:

$$(y')^2=4y^3-g_2y-g_3.$$

in the case that $g_2^3=27g_3^2$. This seems easy, but I can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution $y(z)=\wp(z+c;\omega_1,\omega_2)$ of this differential equation in the general case is called [Weierstrass $\wp$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions):
$$\wp(z;\omega_1,\omega_2)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}}\left\{\frac{1}{(z+m\omega_1+n\omega_2)^2}-\frac{1}{(m\omega_1+n\omega_2)^2}\right\},$$
where
\begin{align}
&g_2=60\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}}\frac{1}{(m\omega_1+n\omega_2)^4},\\
&g_3=140\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}}\frac{1}{(m\omega_1+n\omega_2)^6}.
\end{align}
So I wouldn't call this differential equation easy.

However, for precisely your constraint on parameters ($g_2^3=27g_3^2$) it can be solved in terms of elementary functions. Indeed, parameterizing $g_{2,3}$ as $g_2=3\alpha^2$, $g_3=\alpha^3$ we see that the cubic polynomial on the right has a double root and we get
$$(y')^2=(y-\alpha)(2y+\alpha)^2.$$
This can be integrated (in terms of elementary functions), since because of the double root we can write
$$\int\frac{dy}{(2y+\alpha)\sqrt{y-\alpha}}=\pm z+\mathrm{const}.$$
I suppose you can take it from here.

Comment: Ok, maybe not easy, but I knew from class what the general solution would be. It's funny in fact that the degenerate case is in some way easier, since it can all be done without using any elliptic function theory!